# MySQL - working with SELECT - newbie

Tags: mysql, select

absolute newbie here:

I have table with columns: resource, resource_type_field, value. 
I have this simple query

```
SELECT `resource` FROM `resource_data` WHERE `resource_type_field`=8
```

and would need to take the results, do another query on these results:

```
SELECT `resource` FROM `resource_data` WHERE `value`=2011
```

and than select 'value', where these two queries matches. How is this done?

Thanks for help.

Comment: SELECT `resource` FROM `resource_data` WHERE `resource_type_filed = 8 AND `value` = 2011

Comment: Thanks, but this one doesn't work, as in the table there are multiple rows for each resource. Ie., resource 55 has defined resource_type_field: 8 and value 'resourcename', and on another row resource_type_fiels: 20 and value '2011'. So, when I run the suggested query (which I worked out myself too), it doesn't return any results, as no row has resource_type_filed = 8 AND value` = 2011.

Comment: For anyone looking at this, the code I needed was: `code`SELECT DISTINCT `value` FROM `resource_data` WHERE `resource_type_field`=8 and `resource` IN ( SELECT `resource` FROM `resource_data` WHERE `resource_type_field`=12 AND `value`=2011)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `resource` FROM `resource_data` WHERE `value`=2011 AND `resource_type_field`=8
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `resource` FROM `resource_data` WHERE `resource_type_field`=8 AND `value`=2011;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean operators and other expressions in the [WHERE clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/expressions.html) to combine your conditions.

Finally you need to specify the fields you would like to retrieve in the `SELECT` part.

Maybe you should start by reading a SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

> and than select 'value', where these two queries matches

Since value will always be 2011, use and in where clause

```
SELECT `resource` 
FROM `resource_data` 
WHERE `resource_type_field`=8
  And `value`=2011
```

.

.

Please vote if helps